Gnome to-do app doesn't change dates when modified
I created a task and set it for a certain date. Then I realised that the date was incorrect. I proceeded to change the date. The change reflects in the task info, the task gets placed in the correct order. Yet, when I open the app at a later time, it goes back to the previous date. This happened with multiple tasks.
Is there a 'save' equivalent to save these changes?
